# Spring Rest Controller - Get Mapping - At least one Request Parameter mandatory

Tags: spring, rest, validation, controller, spring-data-jpa

I want to make one of the parameter as mandatory to process a get request.

Do I need to write custom validator for this?

I tried check to check below way

```
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(code) && StringUtils.isEmpty(name) && StringUtils.isEmpty(groupId) && StringUtils.isEmpty(value)) {
      return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

```
@GetMapping(
      value = "getByCriteria"
      )
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<ConfigResponse> getByCriteria(
      @RequestParam(value = "groupId", required = false) String groupId,
      @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
      @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
      @RequestParam(value = "value", required = false) String value) {
// my code here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JSR validation constraints in your controller, something like

```
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Validated
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello(@NotBlank @RequestParam String name) {
        return format("Hello %s!", name);
    }
}
```

And then handle the `ConstraintViolationException` in a `ControllerAdvice` if you want.

Comment: In my case, I need any one of the request parameters mandatory

Comment: You can make it mandatory by setting `required = true`, but to validate that the parameter is not an empty string like your example, you need to add `@NonBlank` or else the user can pass empty strings as an argument even if you set required.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP, how to validate that **one of the parameters** is mandatory.